# Cannot get value from Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a project for my school where I get values from an `EditText` and perform calculations on them, the problem is I can't retrieve values from the `EditText` Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int valuearg1, valuearg2;
    float valuearg3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText arg1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg1);

        EditText arg2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg2);
        EditText arg3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg3);
        try {
            String arg1value = arg1.getText().toString();
            valuearg1 = Integer.parseInt(arg1value);
            String arg2value = arg2.getText().toString();
            valuearg2 = Integer.parseInt(arg2value);
            String arg1value3 = arg3.getText().toString();
            valuearg3 = Float.parseFloat(arg1value3);

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder1.setMessage("Values are :" + valuearg1 + "\n"
                    + valuearg2 + "\n"
                    + valuearg3)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.okay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    builder1.show();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "bug detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is? Show the stacktrace in your logcat perhaps? What does can't retrieve mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are read as soon as the activity is created, since you are reading the values right in `onCreate()`. What you should do is remove all that calculation code form `onCreate()` and simply have declarations of arg1, arg2, arg3 and button. Then `onClick()` of the button should call compute() or some such function that reads values in these `EditText` AFTER the button has been clicked, computes the answer and then displays.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the

```
builder1.setMessage
```

inside the OnClick block.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot, you are trying to get their values the moment after they are created. What you actually do want to do is take the creation of the dialog outside into a different function, not into onCreate().

Comment: Oh okay but where should i get them ? Im a beginner in java and  Android

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting the values there is no value in the EditText boxes because you're getting the value when the activity is created.

You need to get the values when the button click event is called.

Something like this would work:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
int valuearg1, valuearg2;
float valuearg3;

EditText arg1, arg2, arg3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arg1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg1);
    arg2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg2);
    arg3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editArg3);
    try {


        final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Values are :" + valuearg1 + "\n"
                + valuearg2 + "\n"
                + valuearg3)
                .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String arg1value = arg1.getText().toString();
                valuearg1 = Integer.parseInt(arg1value);
                String arg2value = arg2.getText().toString();
                valuearg2 = Integer.parseInt(arg2value);
                String arg1value3 = arg3.getText().toString();
                valuearg3 = Float.parseFloat(arg1value3);

                builder1.setMessage("Values are :" + valuearg1 + "\n"
                        + valuearg2 + "\n"
                        + valuearg3)
                        .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                builder1.show();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "bug detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```